# VECM with mixed Stationarity variables

Tags: econometrics

I have three variables 1) Price 2) harvested Area 3) Yield rate of rice. I am trying to test if there are relationship of each variables between each other so that i can draw some conclusion regarding whether stabilise the rice price can help to stabilise the yield/ harvest area.
I tried to take a log of these three variables in order to better understand them in % change. not that they are skewed.
I then test the stationarity by ADF, showing that only ln (Yield) is stationary. I then perform the common differencing and test again and so on. I finally got ln (Price) after one-time differencing (ln(1)) and ln (Harvest Area) after two time differencing (ln(2)).
I then also conducted the Johansen integration test on the variables ln (Yield), dln (Price) and dd ln (Harvest Area), the result shows that they have cointegration relationship for at least 2 variables. Cointegration test result here
[image]

On the final part, I want to fit those three variables into Vector error correction model.
The problem is here, in order to fit the VECM, all variables should ideally be integrated of the same order, typically I(1) which is not my case here.
if that is a absolute requirement? can my case use VECM? if no, then i should go for VAR instead? or you have other suggestions?